# Why can't I append string to byte slice as the Go reference specified?

Tags: string, go, slice

Quote from the [reference of `append` of Go](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append)

> As a special case, it is legal to append a string to a byte slice, like this:
>   
> `slice = append([]byte("hello "), "world"...)`

But I find I can't do that as this snippet:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main(){
    a := []byte("hello")
    s := "world"
    a = append(a, s) //*Error*: can't use s(type string) as type byte in append 
    fmt.Printf("%s",a)
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You need to use "..." as suffix in order to append a slice to another slice.
Like this:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main(){
    a := []byte("hello")
    s := "world"
    a = append(a, s...) // use "..." as suffice 
    fmt.Printf("%s",a)
}
```

You could try it here: http://play.golang.org/p/y_v5To1kiD